# Writing Postgres function for Hasura

Tags: postgresql, postgis, hasura

I am learning Hasura and Postgres for Postgis support in my project. During learning hasura i encountered Postgres Functions which Hasura can track and i can use them as regular mutation.

Now after apart from Postgres i know about Hasura how it works it is simple wrt to Postgres which different field for me right now. But i tried to create Postgres Function but always failed as i dont know what i am doing. so i head over to hasura so that i can find out something which can help me so i found out this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION search_landmarks_near_user(userid integer, distance_kms integer)
RETURNS SETOF user_landmarks AS $$
  SELECT  A.user_id, A.location,
  (SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(B)) FROM landmark B
   WHERE (
     ST_Distance(
       ST_Transform(B.location::Geometry, 3857),
       ST_Transform(A.location::Geometry, 3857)
     ) /1000) < distance_kms
   ) AS nearby_landmarks
  FROM user_location A where A.user_id = userid
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Now here outer body is much elaborative but after $$ confusion starts to take over me. I have table like this in postgres which contains point(Location) stamp every second.
[Location Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwc4j.png)

What could be the function defination which can return Locations(More than one and single one) near given point in table.

Comment: This is supported by default in Hasura. Check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62974333/calculating-distance-between-a-gps-location-and-postgis-geography-value-using-a/62981936#62981936

Comment: Thank you so so much :)